# How is possible that np.power of 2 does not produce the same number as **2?

Tags: python, numpy

I've just realized that having a number X, np.power(2,X) is not the same as X**2. Here is an example:

```
>>> 1.9975909124103446**2
Out[158]: 3.990369453344393

>>> np.power(2,1.9975909124103446)
Out[159]: 3.993326164628388
```

Any idea about it?

Comment: floating point precision maybe?

Comment: In the first example you are taking 1.9975... to the seconds power, in the second you are taking 2 to the 1.9775... power

Answer (score 4):

You flip-flopped the arguments; the equivalent `np.power` call to `1.9975909124103446**2` is `np.power(1.9975909124103446, 2)`.